# view tree like structure in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, tree

I have Json in tree like structure , and need to show on view template as tree like structure
here is example

```
   [
   {
"Software Products": [
  {
    "Programming Languages": [
      "Java API",
      "Python API"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Documentation": [
      "Java Docs",
      "Python Docs",
      {
        "HTTP Docs": [
          "REST Docs",
          "SOAP Docs"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Try It!"
]
 },
  {
"Cloud Products": [
  "SAAS",
  "PAAS",
  "IAAS"
]
 },
  {
"About Us": [
  {
    "Locations": [
      {
        "India": [
          "Delhi",
          {
            "Mumbai": [
              "Lower Parel",
              "Goregaon"
            ]
          },
          "Bangalore"
        ]
      },
      "USA",
      "Singapore"
    ]
  },
  "Founders",
  "Advisors"
]
 },
"Contact Us"
 ]
```

This is only of the example ,there is no limit of array of object and keys could be changed, How can i show this data on view template as an tree structure?

Comment: What are the things (keys) will be constant in the JSON?

Comment: Dude! common, don't ask us for whole interview assignment.... You just give it a try, if you stuck somewhere then ask here